# Customer is not getting re-indexed and not upgrade via composer

Tags: magento2, migration, magento2-migration-tool

Steps to reproduce
when I do reindex as below, I get the following error. Everything else works except customer is not getting re-indexed. So the in admin I cannot see any customers either although customers are there.

In addition , i cant upgrade Magento 2.1.2 to Magento 2.1.5

```
php -f bin/magento indexer:reindex
Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
SELECT e., e.entity_id, TRIM(CONCAT_WS(' ', IF(e.prefix <> '', e.prefix, NULL), IF(e.firstname <> '', e.firstname, NULL), IF(e.middlename <> '', e.middlename, NULL), IF(e.lastname <> '', e.lastname, NULL), IF(e.suffix <> '', e.suffix, NULL))) AS name, e.email, e.group_id, e.created_at, e.website_id, e.confirmation, e.created_in, e.dob, e.gender, e.taxvat, e.lock_expires, TRIM(CONCAT_WS(' ', IF(shipping.street <> '', shipping.street, NULL), IF(shipping.city <> '', shipping.city, NULL), IF(shipping.region <> '', shipping.region, NULL), IF(shipping.postcode <> '', shipping.postcode, NULL))) AS shipping_full, TRIM(CONCAT_WS(' ', IF(billing.street <> '', billing.street, NULL), IF(billing.city <> '', billing.city, NULL), IF(billing.region <> '', billing.region, NULL), IF(billing.postcode <> '', billing.postcode, NULL))) AS billing_full, billing.firstname AS billing_firstname, billing.lastname AS billing_lastname, billing.telephone AS billing_telephone, billing.postcode AS billing_postcode, billing.country_id AS billing_country_id, billing.region AS billing_region, billing.street AS billing_street, billing.city AS billing_city, billing.fax AS billing_fax, billing.vat_id AS billing_vat_id, billing.company AS billing_company FROM customer_entity AS e
LEFT JOIN customer_address_entity AS shipping ON shipping.entity_id=e.default_shipping
LEFT JOIN customer_address_entity AS billing ON billing.entity_id=e.default_billingCustomer Grid indexer process unknown error:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.lock_expires' in 'field list', query was: SELECT e., e.entity_id, TRIM(CONCAT_WS(' ', IF(e.prefix <> '', e.prefix, NULL), IF(e.firstname <> '', e.firstname, NULL), IF(e.middlename <> '', e.middlename, NULL), IF(e.lastname <> '', e.lastname, NULL), IF(e.suffix <> '', e.suffix, NULL))) AS name, e.email, e.group_id, e.created_at, e.website_id, e.confirmation, e.created_in, e.dob, e.gender, e.taxvat, e.lock_expires, TRIM(CONCAT_WS(' ', IF(shipping.street <> '', shipping.street, NULL), IF(shipping.city <> '', shipping.city, NULL), IF(shipping.region <> '', shipping.region, NULL), IF(shipping.postcode <> '', shipping.postcode, NULL))) AS shipping_full, TRIM(CONCAT_WS(' ', IF(billing.street <> '', billing.street, NULL), IF(billing.city <> '', billing.city, NULL), IF(billing.region <> '', billing.region, NULL), IF(billing.postcode <> '', billing.postcode, NULL))) AS billing_full, billing.firstname AS billing_firstname, billing.lastname AS billing_lastname, billing.telephone AS billing_telephone, billing.postcode AS billing_postcode, billing.country_id AS billing_country_id, billing.region AS billing_region, billing.street AS billing_street, billing.city AS billing_city, billing.fax AS billing_fax, billing.vat_id AS billing_vat_id, billing.company AS billing_company FROM customer_entity AS e
```

Comment: Try this in you cmd promt php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: i get the same log without -f

Comment: I think it's not about reindex problem might be table structure is wrong

Comment: i think you right but how i can fix it? for now , i cant upgrade magento 2.1.2 to magento 2.1.5

Comment: In `indexer_state` table all have status = 'valid'? If not what other status  u have like 'invalid'?

Answer (score 0):

Run below query

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
update indexer_state set status = 'invalid' where status != 'valid';
```

Then run

```
php bin/mangento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: i get SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES =0;# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).
UPDATE indexer_state SET STATUS =  'invalid' WHERE STATUS !=  'valid';# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

Comment: i change it manually and after runing the reindex again i get customer_grid invalid on status

Comment: Run `update indexer_state set status = 'invalid'` then do reindex it should work

Comment: i still get this error. the error related to the table structure on customer module

Comment: Go to `customer_entity` table check in the end u have column `lock_expires` ? It's after first_failure field

Comment: No , i dont have it . i dont even have first_failure field . there is a way to install the the customer scheme again? i dont care if all the data will be deleted

Comment: Can run `magento setup:db-schema:upgrade` & check if it works. Lastly download Magento 2 CE & install that table then it works

Comment: magento setup:db-schema:upgrade i run this command and i get clean log. when i run magento setup:db-data:upgrade i get this following error about lock_expires. i even try to uninstall and install customer table but i cant because its connects to a lot of core modules

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56288/discussion-between-ankit-shah-and-goldy).